# How do i prevent a class referencing its own class?

Tags: c#, class, reference, copy

How do i prevent making a class implicitly referencing to its own class?

example:

```
class foo
{
    public foo(int y)
    {
        x = y;
    }
    public int x;
}
class program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        foo myFoo1 = new foo(10);
        foo myFoo2 = myFoo1; //How do i prevent this?
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious to know what situation you have in mind, where you want to prevent this.

Comment: Maybe he's confused how to implement singleton in C#?  Doesn't know about `static` classes and such?  I'm just guessing.

Comment: Why would you want to prevent it?

Comment: @Kevin: singleton or statics would not help. He is not preventing multiple instances, he is preventing multiple references to the same instance.

Comment: Well, its just kinda a special situation where i just dont want to make it happend... neither with structs or classes :)

Comment: @Assassinbeast: I understand you "just" dont want it to happen. But if you told us why, we might be able to help you. You are now looking for an answer in a technical corder. But tell us on a functional level, what you ar trying to do or trying to prevent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot prevent this. `myFoo1` is of type `foo`, so it can be assigned to `myFoo2`, period.

In any case, it's not clear what you believe can be gained by preventing this. Since `foo` is a reference type (a `class`), the result of the assignment is that where previously you had only one name with which to refer to the `foo` object you created, you now have two. Since the names are just there for the developer's convenience, there is no difference in the behavior of your program. The assignment does not create another object.

Note that if `foo` were a value type (a `struct`) then the assignment would make a *copy* of the value; `myFoo1` and `myFoo2` would be completely independent from each other.

Comment: maybe when the object is disposable he might want to control the references, but then weak references would be far better.

Comment: @KeithNicholas: Controlling references is easy: don't hand them out to other code. Plus, handing them out or not is completely orthogonal to how many references to the same instance you have at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't restrict variables in that way. A variable of type *X* can reference any instance of an object of type *X* (for classes) / can be assigned any valid value of type *X* (for structs).

The only thing you can do is make `foo` a struct, since assignment of a struct produces a new *copy* of that struct. For example:

```
struct foo
{
    public int x;

    public foo(int y)
    {
        x = y;
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    foo myFoo1 = new foo(10);
    foo myFoo2 = myFoo1;
    myFoo2.x = 5;
    Console.WriteLine(myFoo1.x); // 10
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, you're confused about what you think is happening (or at the very least, the wording).

In C#, there are objects in memory, and references to those objects. When you do

`foo myFoo1 = new foo(10);`

`myFoo1` is a reference, and the value of a reference is the place in memory where a `foo` type object is stored.

When you do

`foo myFoo2 = myFoo1;`

myFoo2 is a reference, and the value of a reference is the place in memory where a `foo` type object is stored - the exact same object. Both references are doing identical things, indistinguishably.

`myFoo2` and `myFoo1` are doing identical things, so how could you prevent one while allowing the other?

If you mean 'how do I prevent two variables from referencing the same object?' there are two solutions, depending on what you mean:

1. If the problem is that you have two variables referencing the same object, one variable mutates the object and the other variable 'unexpectedly' sees the changes, make the object immutable and 'mutations' of the object actually return a new, immutable object with the changes made.
2. You can make the object a struct. Structs are referenced by value, not by reference, so when you make one variable 'point' to another variable's struct, it copies the entire struct into the new variable instead of copying a reference.